# find if a facebook user likes my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

i'm using this piece of code for doing this but it always returns me "not a fan!".
What i'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
require 'php-sdk/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '107896139417411',
'secret' => '6c98823d8b938ec92eb6846c17bc0156',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$page_id = "406604096078918";

if ($user) {
try {
$likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/".$page_id);
if( !empty($likes['data']) )
    echo "I like!";
else
    echo "not a fan!";
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

if ($user) {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' => 'user_likes'
 ));
}

?>
```

Can anyone help me in this issiue please? It's very important to me :').
Thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine for me, try var_dump($likes) and start debugging

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the permission "user_likes" in your code? Without this permission you cannot get a user's likes'